# Javascript Inheritance with 3 separated files

Tags: javascript, html, inheritance

Hi I have 3 javascript files: Game.js, Player.js, Drawable.js.
Now in Game.js I want to create an object _player, that is Drawable and than that is Player. This means that _player is a Player Object, that is a class that EXTENDS Drawable.

**Drawable.js**

```
function Drawable(x, y, src)
{
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.src = src;
  this.width = this.img.width;
  this.height = this.img.height;

  this.draw = function(canvas) 
  {   
    canvas.drawImage(this.img,this.x, this.y);
  }

  this.midpoint = function() 
  {
    return {
      x: this.x + this.width/2,
      y: this.y + this.height/2};
    }

  }
}
```

**Player.js**

```
function Player()
{
  this.moveLeft = function()
  {
    this.x -= 3;
  }

  this.moveRight = function()
  {
    this.x += 3;
  }

  this.moveUp = function() 
  {
    this.y -= 3;
  }

  this.moveDown = function()
  {
    this.y += 3;
  }
}
```

**Game.js**

```
var _player;

 _player = new Player();

 _player.draw(...);
 _player.moveLeft();
 ...
 ...
```

This is what I want to do. I've tried to put Player.prototype = new Drawable; but It doesn't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want player objects to behave such that you can call

```
player.draw(...);
player.moveLeft(...);
```

then the `draw` and `moveLeft` functions need to be stored as properties in every player object (yikes) or somewhere on a player object's prototype chain.

Which brings up one comment on your actual code: those functions should be in prototypes, not the actual objects.

So, to answer your actual problem...

- The first thing you should do is place the methods in prototypes.
- Then you need to make the prototype of a player's prototype be the prototype for all drawables.

That may sound confusing, but here is the money line:

```
Player.prototype = Object.create(Drawable.prototype);
```

Do this *before* creating players with `new Player`. :)

**ADDENDUM**

[*Live Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/wtdM3/) -- which also shows you how to do the "constructor" thing so you can build a player with an initial x and y.

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript is a language that has a class based object model which is modeled on top of the prototype object model of javascript. On their page you can see an example [how the extends keyword works](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) in coffeescript when it is compiled to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It might not have been a consideration for you. Perhaps it's not something that you've ever given any thought, but why not make a `Drawable` component, which you give to a Player, through dependency-injection, either during construction or shortly after.

```
var Drawable = function () { ... };
var Player = function () { ... };


var player = new Player(new Drawable(), new Controlable(), new Physical());
```